# Automated download of excel file in vba

Tags: excel, vba, download, automation

I've had a look around and I think I need some very specific help. I need to write a macro to download excel files online. Until now I have been able to use the URLdownloadtofile function by adding the get request parameters to the URL. The website I need to download from this time however doesn't seem to work that way. (It ends in aspx, if that makes a difference). I use http fox addin on Firefox to see the request line and all it gives is the website and no parameters after it. How can I use xmlhttp to download this file if I can't use URLdownloadtofile? Also one of the dropdown menus only becomes active when the previous menu value is selected.

The URL of the file is: http://cmg.cdec-sic.cl/Modulos/CMg/CDEC_CMgBarras.aspx

If I want the excel file for January 2014, tension 220 and barra alto jahuel_220 for instance, what would I need to place after the send function of the xmlhttp function? As in what parameters? I tried using the names of each parameter = to the value I want. And I changed all the $ to the hex value. But it just seemed to return the same page.

And once that works, how do I get the returned excel file to download to a specific directory?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, _
ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Dim Ret As Long

Sub Download_Files_from_web_and_save_to_file()
Dim strURL As String
Dim strPath As String    

Ret = URLDownloadToFile(0, " http://cmg.cdec-sic.cl/Modulos/CMg/CDEC_CMgBarras.aspx", "d:\my_file.xls", 0, 0)


       If Ret = 0 Then
         ' MsgBox "File successfully downloaded"
       Else
          MsgBox "Unable to download the file"
      End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It would be better if you added an explanation to your answer.